# Control Content On Non-Blog Pages

Tags: customization, pages, content, static-website

I'm new to WordPress, trying to learn it's capabilities.

**My Goal**

My goal is to make a normal website but have it's content (text and images) be adjustable by the user / client, managed content.

An example navigation may be:

- Home (normal web page)
- About (normal web page)
- Services (normal web page)
- Contact Us (normal web page)
- Blog (blog page)

**My Question**

Is this achievable? So far, it seems that WordPress is so blog-page-centric, that only via *Posts* would one be able to go in and make changes, but I want the user to be able to say, edit the address on the contact and home page at any time.

I know it's most likely *possible*, but I'm having a very hard time finding resources that don't talk about creating a blog-like theme. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You just go into _Pages_, and click the page you want to edit, then you can edit it. Have you set the site up yet? Where are you having trouble?

Comment: Well, I'm use to building things from scratch, not using WYSIWYG. I'd like to have extremely custom html / css, then simply output the correct content, like text, into those areas. Maybe it's loop related or something. The goal is that if they need to change something, they don't have to come to me to edit source code.

Comment: You must use page builder (visual composer or beaver builder), if you want to give a client to access, a part component on specific page, like address or image.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. I've seen Elementor as a very popular one, right? So, basically via a plugin would be the only / best way. Thank you, @Manyang

Comment: yeah elementor is good also.. Your welcome

Comment: If you want full control over the markup and styling, you can [create your own blocks for the editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/), or use a custom fields plugin (like Advanced Custom Fields) to add fields to the editor that you can use to populate your templates.